# Require admin role for ServiceStack's RegistrationFeature

Tags: servicestack

How would I add users to an `IAuthRepository` without allowing self-registration? Is there a way to require a certain role (e.g. admin) for the `RegistrationFeature`, or would it be easier to create a separate project with only the `RegistrationFeature` only running on localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want users to be able to register themselves then maybe you don't want to enable the `RegistrationFeature` itself which is not registered by default.

You'll have more flexibility in just [using the IAuthRepository itself in your own Service to create users](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/a5623a3caa64b1e3670e154fe404ba61d7470571/src/ServiceStack/Auth/RegisterService.cs#L109-L125).

[ServiceStack's new Auth Templates](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.5#using-servicestack-auth-in-mvc) shows examples of using the `IAuthRepository` to create Users on Startup, e.g:

```
if (authRepo.GetUserAuthByUserName("user@gmail.com") == null)
{
    var testUser = authRepo.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth
    {
        DisplayName = "Test User",
        Email = "user@gmail.com",
        FirstName = "Test",
        LastName = "User",
    }, "p@55wOrd");
}

if (authRepo.GetUserAuthByUserName("manager@gmail.com") == null)
{
    var roleUser = authRepo.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth
    {
        DisplayName = "Test Manager",
        Email = "manager@gmail.com",
        FirstName = "Test",
        LastName = "Manager",
    }, "p@55wOrd");
    authRepo.AssignRoles(roleUser, roles:new[]{ "Manager" });
}

if (authRepo.GetUserAuthByUserName("admin@gmail.com") == null)
{
    var roleUser = authRepo.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth
    {
        DisplayName = "Admin User",
        Email = "admin@gmail.com",
        FirstName = "Admin",
        LastName = "User",
    }, "p@55wOrd");
    authRepo.AssignRoles(roleUser, roles:new[]{ "Admin" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I've found out how:

```
typeof(RegisterService).AddAttributes(new RequiredRoleAttribute("Admin"));
```

More here: https://docs.servicestack.net/restricting-services